# How can I draw a customized line in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, alignment, drawing

why GIMP makes so difficult to draw a simple line on an image! Anyway, could someone help me out and explain how can I draw a line in several layers of certain length and width and then align those lines. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's difficult because that's not really what GIMP is for. It's a photo editor first and foremost.  Better to use a vector image editor. Inkscape is free and Open Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a [path](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-paths.html) with just two points. In your case, this is basically starting the Paths tools and clicking twice, once on each point. You can use guides (the dotted blue lines) to mark the points, or your can move the points after creating them (when your pointer is near a movable point, the move cross symbol is added to it, you can then click and drag).

[image]

- Then select each layer in turn and use `Edit > Stroke path` to render the line on the layer. You possibly want to use the `Line` mode. The line is stroked with the foreground color.

[image]

The lines will be rendered at the very same place on all layers.

If the required line is not straight, the method still holds, the path is only a bit more complex (use of tangents, etc...).