# Creating line that looks like a hose in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I'm new to gimp and need to create many diagrams in gimp.  I would like a quick way to draw a line that looks like a hose/pipe between pieces of equipment.  It doesn't have to be perfect but quick to do and recognizable as a pipe/hose.  The method I used to draw this was in QGIS, but it is very time consuming and memory intensive.

Example below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use [paths](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-path-stroke.html)? See also [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/96293/how-to-trace-pattern-along-a-path-in-gimp) and [this other question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/158519/how-can-i-draw-a-customized-line-in-gimp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use paths:

[image]

and just do `Edit > Stroke path` in `Line mode`

[image]

For a slightly more realistic look, you can use a brush.

Create an image with

- A crescent on transparent background (about the size of your wider pipes or larger, here 50x50px)
- Filled with a bi-linear gradient between a color and a slightly darker version of that color
- You can make a circle selection, fill it, and then delete a half circle, or make a crescent selection (select circle and then subtract half-circle)

[image]

- Then copy the image to the clipboard (`Select > All`, `Edit > Copy`), open the paint tool and set these options:

  - Brush: `Clipboard image`
  - Size: as required
  - Spacing: something small (1,2...)
  - Brush dynamics: `Track direction`

[image]

Then use `Edit > Stroke path` in `Paint tool mode` and select the Paintbrush and `Emulate paint dynamics`.

[image]

You can save your brush image as a plain Gimp brush for later use if interested, and it will be added to the brushes list.

For the record there is also a script that can draw a bilinear gradient along a path a gives a cleaner result:

[image]

Ask in comments if interested.

To use the plugin:

1. Create a path...
2. Set the current gradient to something light to dark, for instance, I created the gradient ❶ using the `FG to BG (RGB)` gradient, and then setting the FG ❷ and BG colors ❸.

[image]

3. Call the script form the Paths list, right click you path and `Decorate > Gradient long path` towards the bottom

[image]

Then mostly set the width in the dialog:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the bi-gradient plugin, but clueless on how you got to the look in your last image.

Comment: See augmented answer. See installation instructions at the bottom of the download page.